# Why isn't this a violation of Stokes' theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

> Consider the one-form $\alpha = \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2 + y^2}$ on
>    $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Let $i: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2
>  \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ be the inclusion.
>
> Compute $\int_{S^1} i^*\alpha$. Does there exist $f \in
>  C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\})$ such that $df = \alpha$.
>   Show that $d \alpha = 0$, and explain why combining this with Stokes'
>   theorem does not give a contradiction.

Attempt:

Denote the unit sphere with boundary by $D$. Then

$$\int_{S^1} i^*\alpha = \int_{S^1}i^{*}(xdy-ydx)= \int_D dx \land dy - dy \land dx = 2 \int_D dx \land dy = 2 \pi$$
where Stokes' theorem was used. 
There does not exist an $f$ with $df = \alpha$. I'm not entirely sure how I can formally show this. This would imply that $\partial f/\partial x = 1/2\ln(x^2 + y^2)$ and integrating we get something like $f(x,y) = 1/2\ln(x^2 + y^2)c(y)+ d(y)$ and I gueuss the $\ln$ is problematic.

Further, I was able to show that $d \alpha = 0$ with a direct computation but I can't see why this doesn't Stokes' theorem.

EDIT: Is the problem the following? If one is naive, one would say that

$$\int_{S^1} i^* \alpha = \int_Dd \alpha$$

but this doesn't make sense because $\alpha$ is not defined at the origin!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: To apply Stokes's Theorem on $D$ you would need to know that $\alpha$ is smooth everywhere inside $D$. Of course, there's a problem at the origin.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the first part of the problem, I'm guessing they want you to say:
If there was such an $f$, then you would have
$$\int_{S^1} i^*\alpha = \int_{S^1} i^* df = \int_{S^1} di^*f = \int_{\partial S^1 =\varnothing} i^*f = 0$$
by Stokes' theorem, but you just computed that this integral is not 0.

Comment: Hi. I have a problem. Doesn't $f(x,y)= \arctan(y/x)$ satisfy the first part of the problem?

Comment: The derivatives are correct, but your function is not defined on $\{x=0\}$. This is the main issue. Your function comes from polar coordinates $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$. The angle coordinate can never be extended to a smooth function on all of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Conversely, any function with $df = \alpha$ locally must be the angle function up to addition of a constant. In other words, if an answer existed, it would have to basically "be" $\arctan(y/x)$, but $\arctan(y/x)$ doesn't work, so no answer exists.